# Detect if file exists after ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I am using the ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT intent when creating a file in my app. One user complained that he had lost data because he overwrote an existing file without getting a warning.

1.) Is there any way to find out if the returned document exists?

2.) What's the recommended workflow for this?

Comment: Not that it answers the question, but as far as I can tell ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT will not override an existing file.  I have only tested local storage and google drive.  For local storage it creates a file with " (n)" appended to it.  In Drive it will happily create a second file of the same name in the same location.

Comment: I'm not seeing the (n) appended if I retype the name...  I'll play with it further, but not sure that's right.  I'll add that it does seem to be an issue because you can't check if the file exists AFTER the URL was chosen because it gets created by the act of picking it.  You can't rename the file yourself, because I think you'll lose the permission grant.  And you can't do BEFORE, because you don't know what the user will enter as the name.  An interesting problem.